# How can I access parameters defined in parameters.yml from within a twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony2.

How can I access parameters defined in parameters.yml from within a twig template ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define it in `config.yml` like this:

```
twig:
    globals:
        some_key: %some_key%
```

and then use in twig files like:

```
{{ some_key }}
```

For security reasons you can't get access to data from `parameters.yml` in the templates without defining global twig variables.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you explain about the security risk ?

Comment: You should not be able to disclose your sensitive data (parameters.yml should contain primarily only such data) in your templates. Read about [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).